# How to run a jar file using specefic runtime parameters

Tags: java, jar

I have a .jar file from a project I build, but whenever I run it, I use specific flags in Terminal (specifically -xDock).  Is there a way to configure a .jar so that when I double click on the file it will run using whatever flags I use in terminal?

Comment: the best way is to write a bash script that will do that for you

Comment: Your `main` method could simply assume some defaults ...

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make it the Java way you can change the Java code to have default parameters - then you can just run it without. Or you can make it take its configuration from a config file and once you change that config file it will not require additional params.

If you have no control on the java code and you have a specific jar you want to double click then you can do it the windows way ;) Create a shortcut and in the Target: field add the jar with parameters

Or you can create a batch / sh file that runs it with specific params

Answer (score 0):

If the parameters aren't dynamically changeable write them hard-coded or use this solution as default parameters when other parameters aren't passed.

Answer (score 0):

Another interesting way of doing this, is by using JarSplice.
It's a tiny program that lets you add arguments into a sort of "wrapper" around the Jar. Then when you open it up, the arguments will be passed with it.